# xarray - how to group or resample time series data by yyyy-01-01 and yyyy-07-01 over multiple years

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-xarray

My time serries data is a xarray' DataArray object called `da_output_halfyearly`:

```
<xarray.DataArray '__xarray_dataarray_variable__' (time: 10, latitude: 106, longitude: 193)>
dask.array<shape=(4, 106, 193), dtype=int32, chunksize=(2, 106, 193)>
Coordinates:
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 -39.2 -39.149525 ... -33.950478 -33.9
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 140.8 140.84792 140.89584 ... 149.95209 150.0
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 1972-01-01 1972-07-01 1973-01-01 1973-07-01 ... 1981-01-01 1981-07-01
```

I will need to group/resample the data into two time groups "yyyy-01-01" and "yyyy-07-01" and take std() off the data in each group.

I was able to use index selecting to split the data into two separate DataArray objects:

```
da_all_jan_jun = da_output_halfyearly[::2]
da_all_jul_dec = da_output_halfyearly[1::2]

da_jan_jun_std = da_all_jan_jun.std(dim='time')
da_jul_dec_std = da_all_jul_dec.std(dim='time')
```

However, the output DataArray objects lost the `time` dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you are starting from the following setup:

```py
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

times = pd.date_range('2000', periods=100, freq='M')
da = xr.DataArray(range(len(times)), [('time', times)])
resampled = da.resample(time='6MS', closed='left').sum('time')
```

A quick way to achieve something close to your desired result is to use `groupby`, grouping by the month of the year:

```py
result = resampled.groupby('time.month').std('time')
```

This will leave you with a resulting `DataArray` that has a `'month'` dimension, with values of either `1` or `7`:

```py
<xarray.DataArray (month: 2)>
array([160.269218, 164.972725])
Coordinates:
  * month    (month) int64 1 7
```

If you want labels that are a little more descriptive, you could construct a `DataArray` to use for grouping, e.g.

```py
jan_jun = xr.full_like(resampled.time, 'jan-jun', dtype='<U7')
jul_dec = xr.full_like(resampled.time, 'jul-dec', dtype='<U7')
labels = xr.where(resampled.time.dt.month == 1, jan_jun, jul_dec)
labels = labels.rename('time')
result = resampled.groupby(labels).std('time')
```

In this case, the result looks like:

```py
<xarray.DataArray (time: 2)>
array([160.269218, 164.972725])
Coordinates:
  * time   (time) object 'jan-jun' 'jul-dec'
```